# How to properly animate SCNView height?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, scenekit

I'm trying to animate SCNView height, but it seems like there are some visual issue.

When content is growing it looks like everything is ok, but when I'm trying to decrease the height, view just jumps to final height instantly.

```
let newHeight = scene.frame.height + (open ? 100.0 : -100.0)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.scene.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: newHeight)
}) { finished in
    self.open = !self.open
}
```

See
[Code Running in Sumulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKzlL.gif)

With regular view everything works fine.

Comment: it seems like you have not calculated the frame with respect to safe are.

Comment: @MahendraGP [here](https://imgur.com/01wGvLe) you can find animation on iPhone 8 with no safe area. Animation engine changes view height instantly to the anchorPoint position and then starts "broken" animation

Comment: Now it looks like the frame is set before the animation.

Comment: @MahendraGP you can test it by your own. Just create empty project, add SCNView and try to animate its height back and forward. This code works well with regular view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `contentMode` of `SCNView` to `.scaleToFill` where needed (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`). It works as expected.

```
let view: SCNView 
...
view.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

Comment: It seems like if set contentMode in storyboard for SCNView, it doesn't really affect scene. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a relationship between this behavior and the content mode of `scene`. You may try:

```
             scene.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```